# Observe event inside loop

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a UI matrix of action buttons that increase in value by one when clicked (Counter with a different value for each button through ObserveEvent). I would like to have access to those values in R after closing my shiny app in the form of a matrix, for sport scouting purposes.
So far what I did was, to create a separate variable for each button, and to copy paste the same counter function again and again. But obviously this results in ugly code and long waits when launching, even though it works. I would like to shorten my code by creating a loop in the server part, maybe by doing a matrix of those "storage" values and making the loop add one to the values when the related action button is activated in the UI. 
I included my code below, please be kind, I'm no programmer and have little experience!
Thank you.

```
a_OH1_z1_q1 <- 0

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "Scouting",
    id = "navtab",
    tabPanel("Attack",
             navlistPanel(
               tabPanel('OH1',
                        mainPanel(
                          tags$b("______1____________2____________3_____________4______"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z1q1", a_OH1_z1_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z1q2", a_OH1_z1_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z1q3", a_OH1_z1_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z1q4", a_OH1_z1_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z2q1", a_OH1_z2_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z2q2", a_OH1_z2_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z2q3", a_OH1_z2_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z2q4", a_OH1_z2_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z3q1", a_OH1_z3_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z3q2", a_OH1_z3_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z3q3", a_OH1_z3_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z3q4", a_OH1_z3_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z4q1", a_OH1_z4_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z4q2", a_OH1_z4_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z4q3", a_OH1_z4_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z4q4", a_OH1_z4_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z5q1", a_OH1_z5_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z5q2", a_OH1_z5_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z5q3", a_OH1_z5_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z5q4", a_OH1_z5_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("aOH1z6q1", a_OH1_z6_q1,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z6q2", a_OH1_z6_q2,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z6q3", a_OH1_z6_q3,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                          actionButton("aOH1z6q4", a_OH1_z6_q4,
                                       style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;")
                        )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(
    input$aOH1z1q1,{
      a_OH1_z1_q1 <<- a_OH1_z1_q1 + 1
      updateActionButton(session,"aOH1z1q1",label = a_OH1_z1_q1)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I can't get past scrolling through that much code. Would you consider shortening it to 2 or 3 things to track instead of ... that many? As long as your question says "I have more than 2 of these, a generic solution is preferred", you should get the answer you need.

Comment: Scrolling questions on SO can be a strong deterrent for people (like me) to read. I think in general programmers on SO understand two things well: (1) if somebody repeats code more than twice, generalize it; (2) if you say *"I show 2-3 here but really there are dozens"*, we will honor your intent and generalize it. You need people to at least *look* at your code, but I'm not even going to look at it when it's this long. It's daunting! :-) (Further, you already have a close-vote ... it only takes 3 votes to close a question, don't give other readers an excuse to demand better clarity. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Do this:

```
library(shiny)

loadBackup <- function(x){
  if(file.exists(x)){
    init <- readRDS(x)
  } else {
    init <- NULL
  }
  return(init)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "Scouting",
    id = "navtab",
    tabPanel("Attack",
             navlistPanel(
               tabPanel('OH1',
                        mainPanel(
                          tags$b("______1____________2____________3_____________4______"),
                          br(),
                          uiOutput(outputId = "CustomUI")
                        )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(length = 4,
                       width = 4)
  initialize <- reactive({
   backup <- matrix(0, nrow = rv$length, ncol = rv$width)
   .backup <- loadBackup("backup.rds")
   if(!is.null(.backup)){
     dim <- dim(.backup)
     backup[1:dim[1],1:dim[2]] <- .backup
   }
   for(x in 1:rv$length){
     for(y in 1:rv$width){
       rv[[paste0("a_OH1_z",x,"_q",y)]] <- backup[x,y]
     }
   }
  })


  savebackup <- reactive({
  backup <- matrix(0, nrow = rv$length, ncol = rv$width)
    for(x in 1:rv$length){
      for(y in 1:rv$width){
        backup[x,y] <- rv[[paste0("a_OH1_z",x,"_q",y)]] + input[[paste0("aOH1z",x,"q",y)]]
      }
    }
    saveRDS(backup, file = "backup.rds")
  })
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    isolate(savebackup())
  })


  output$CustomUI <- renderUI({
    initialize()
    column(12,
           lapply(1:rv$length, function(x){
             fluidRow(
               br(),
               lapply(1:rv$width, function(y, x){
                 actionButton(paste0("aOH1z",x,"q",y), 
                              rv[[paste0("a_OH1_z",x,"_q",y)]],
                              style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;")
               }, x = x)
             )


           })
    )
  })

  observe(

    lapply(1:rv$length, function(x){
      lapply(1:rv$width, function(y, x){
        z <- rv[[paste0("a_OH1_z",x,"_q",y)]] + input[[paste0("aOH1z",x,"q",y)]]
        updateActionButton(session,paste0("aOH1z",x,"q",y),label = z)
      }, x = x)
    })
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`LoadBackup` will check for a specific file, if it finds it it will return it's value, if not, it returns 0.

Files are saved when the session ends with the `session$onSessionEnded` call back function. The UI is built using an `lapply` which I adapted from [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html) example given by RStudio.

The entire UI is built from the width and length reactive values that I specify, so the user may increase the size as they wish. You could remove this and make it inputs and it should still work the same.

RDS files are saved locally on the device so this will not be reproducible on shinyapps.io. You will need to look for database solutions for that.